# I'm looking for a way to add a handler to Netty in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I need to build an ODATA API and am Considering using Micronaut, would like to install a handler in Netty.

Such as https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata4/tree/master/lib/server-api/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/netty/server/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any bean that implements ChannelOutboundHandler will be added to the Netty pipeline after the HttpServerCodec